# CDF on non-standardized t distribution

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, t-distribution

What is the cumulative distribution function of the non-standardized student's t distribution in terms of inverse scaling parameter? I have found a number of related equations online, but not this one specifically. According to Wikipedia, the PDF in this form is:

$$
p\left(x \middle| v, \mu, \lambda\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{v+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{v}{2}\right)}\left(\frac{\lambda}{\pi{}v}\right)^{\frac{1}{2}}\left(1+\frac{\lambda\left(x-\mu\right)^2}{v}\right)^{-\frac{v+1}{2}}
$$

Comment: A good starting point is to specify the functional form of the pdf you are working with ...

Comment: The [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Student%27s_t-distribution) gives the Student t CDF explicitly (as a multiple of a hypergeometric function). Since it is so straightforward to shift and rescale the argument, it would seem there is no need to spell it out, so I surmise the difficulty you encounter is associated with this "inverse scaling parameter."  Exactly what does that mean?

Comment: I added the pdf from wikipedia.

Comment: This sounds like routine bookwork. Is this for some subject? Since you have precision $\lambda$, you should make it explicit that the inverse-scaling parameter in your formulation is (rather oddly to my eyes), $\sqrt{\lambda}$. In any case, you simply take the cdf in the Wikipedia article for the t-distribution and replace $x$ by the shifted-and-rescaled $x$. I hesitate to post a one-line answer, though.